# How to show an icon in a TButton?

Tags: user-interface, delphi

My main form has a TActionList component connected to TImageList. The problem is that the TImageList was moved recently in a DataModule. Now when I assign an action to a TButton, the image associated to that action does not appear in the button.

How to fix this, while keeping the image list in the data module?

Comment: It works for me. Of course, the DM's unit must be included in the form's unit, and the `Button`'s `Images` property must be (re)set to the image list.

Comment: Does TButton in your version of Delphi support an image? (I use Delphi 5 and it does not). Maybe you should use TSpeedButton instead?

Comment: Try opening the datamodule's unit in the IDE

Comment: Has the ActionList been updated to the new location of the ImageList ?.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - The image list was not available in the object inspector because the data module (that contained the image list) was indeed not present in the Uses list. I really got the impression that I put it there. Looks like my Uses Cleaner tool (cnpack) was a bit overzealous. 

If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @MundoPeter - Yes, no need to TBitBtn anymore. TButton support images now. I really think that Embarcadero tries to milk money from us, and that is not worth to buy every single upgrade (especially not the subscription). But, in your case I would definitively recommend to take out some money and upgrade to Delphi Rio (I have Rio and is stable enough) or Sydney (I have a free license, but I never tried Sydney because they just released it - I wait for the second patch then I upgrade). Or look around for an XE7 second hand license if you are from EU. Just see what's new since Delphi 5.

Comment: @MundoPeter - By the way, if you are not up to date, Embarcadero offers a free edition of Delphi now for non commercial applications (best decision taken in the last 25 years of Delphi existence). Take a look into that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

Of course, the DM's unit must be included in the form's unit (in a `uses` list), and the `TButton`'s `Images` property must be (re)set to the image list.

Answer (score 2):

You Should assign the Images Property in TButton To the same ImageList.